# Add GroupBox in a layout

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout, qgroupbox

I am using Qt 5.15.3, with Qt cretor.

I would like to add a QGroupBox in a QVBoxLayout

Does anyone have an idea to add it in the layout ?

Here is what I have tried :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QGroupBox>

QVBoxLayout *layoutOption = new QVBoxLayout;
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox("Some text");

layoutOption->addWidget(checkbox);

QGroupBox *optionGB = new QGroupBox("Options");
optionGB->setLayout(layoutOption);


//trying to add optionGB in globalLayout
QVBoxLayout *globalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
globalLayout->addLayout(optionGB);
```

And the issue is :

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'QLayout *' with an lvalue of type 'QGroupBox *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this way:

```
//trying to add optionGB in globalLayout
QVBoxLayout *globalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
globalLayout->addWidget(optionGB);
```